# Is this very efficient?

Tags: java, performance, minecraft

In my minecraft clone I am creating a specific type of item called ***food***(came up with it myself).

In order to control the food amount I did this:

```
    if (currentFoodAmount > maxFoodAmount) {

        currentFoodAmount = maxFoodAmount;
    }

    if (currentFoodAmount < 0) {

        currentFoodAmount = 0;
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Thanks for all the help to those who answered (the sarcasism and constructive critisism included)

p.s.s. the full code:

```
            if (currentFoodAmount > maxFoodAmount) {

        EntityPlayer.giveEffect(Effect.full);
        currentFoodAmount = maxFoodAmount;
    }

    if (currentFoodAmount < 0) {

        currentFoodAmount = 0;
    }

    if (currentFoodAmount == 0) {

        EntityPlayer.giveEffect(Effect.starved);
    }

        public static void tick() {

    if (!EntityPlayer.isDead) {

        --foodDecayRate;

        if (foodDecayRate == 0) {

            currentFoodAmount -= 5;
            foodDecayRate = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's likely as good as you'll get. But really don't worry about efficiency on this level: computers are fast for simple operations. Worry about efficiency of your algorithms, about not allocating too much memory, etc.

Comment: You can make the code a bit shorter using Math.max and Math.min.

Comment: That's not worth an answer really: the answer ought to show how it can't be done better in Java bytecode.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a micro-optimisation to me. If your code being fast hinges on this when you have other problems to deal with.

Comment: Google **"Donald Knuth Premature Optimization"**, read it over and over again until you realize what a ridiculous question this is, then read it a few more times!

Comment: this question illustrates you don't know what makes a program *run as fast as possible*, I can tell you from experience, code like this has nothing to do with optimizations of execution time ( or space ), if you think it does, then you need some really fundamental knowledge you don't have. Have you read up on Knuth's quote and why this type of question illustrates such a fundamental gap in knowledge as to be harmful?

Comment: they actually didn't give you any constructive answers, they are not answering the valuable answer, which is what I commented with. **the question is wrong!** and why it is not a valid question because this isn't a valid concern. The valid answer is learn to **profile** and only concern yourself with these types of issues when empirical profiling shows that they are a valid concern. In 1980 getting rid of a clock cycle or two was a valid concern, but those were 1Mhz chips. The valuable answer is at your stage, **don't concern yourself with these things**, correctness first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Less efficient, but more readable, using java Math library. Here a little example:

```
  currentFoodAmount = Math.min(currentFoodAmount, maxFoodAmount);
  currentFoodAmount = Math.max(currentFoodAmount, 0);
```

More efficient, but less readable:

```
  currentFoodAmount = currentFoodAmount > 0 ? (currentFoodAmount < maxFoodAmount ? currentFoodAmount : maxFoodAmount ) : 0;
```

Comment: Is that definitely more efficient, though? I'd have thought two method calls, albeit static ones, would be more expensive unless they get inlined, and in that case it'll end up as the same code he already has won't it?

Comment: I preffer this way over all else thanks. Although I've seen Math used before  I've nver used it (Math not math)

Comment: wait why wouldnt it be 

        currentFoodAmount = Math.min(currentFoodAmount, 0);
  currentFoodAmount = Math.max(currentFoodAmount, maxFoodAmount);

Comment: Because if 0 is lower than currentFoodAmount, then you want to take the max value (0), and if currentFoodAmount is greater of maxFoodAmount you want to take the min value (maxFoodAmount)

Comment: Um that sounds backwards still, im most likly over thinking it

Answer (score 2):

```
if (currentFoodAmount > maxFoodAmount) {

    currentFoodAmount = maxFoodAmount;
} else if (currentFoodAmount < 0) {

    currentFoodAmount = 0;
}
```

by adding the else it will be a bit more efficient (assembly point of view)
so if it run first if , will not check for second condition

Comment: unless `maxFoodAmount` is negative

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a more efficient way that I know of. Most problems of efficiency involve creating unnecessary objects or variables that drain memory, neither of which you are doing.

You should only worry about the efficiency of small snippets of code if they are being run several times per second, i.e. on every refresh.

You only have six neat lines of code, don't be to hard on yourself.

Comment: you mean *"several thousand times a second, constantly"*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save lines, you can come up with a pretty ugly ternary statement:

```
currentFoodAmount = currentFoodAmount > maxFoodAmount ? maxFoodAmount : (
    currentFoodAmount < 0 ? 0 : currentFoodAmount);
```

It's admittedly really hard to read, but if you're into saving lines of code, here you go.

---

#### More on Ternary

The ternary operator operates on a single conditional which evaluates to either `true` or `false` and then returns the value corresponding to the result.

Meaning if you have a statement like this:

```
x = y == 0 ? 1 : 2;
```

Your `x` variable will be set to `1` if `y == 0`. If `y != 0`, then `x` will be set to `2`;

The ternary format in Java looks like this:

```
conditional ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

Do note that this technique is often frowned upon, as it often  makes code difficult to read as opposed to a more verbose `if`/`else` clause.

Comment: I think that is realy complex, though I have seen it used before, I have never used, nor do I understand, the ?.

could you link me to a tutorial on it?

Comment: same for the : too actualy

Comment: oh it sounds so useful i will favorite this question for easy access